# Large images on Android with Titanium

Tags: javascript, android, image, titanium, android-imageview

I need to display a huge image (at least 2000x2000) on Android with Titanium and let the user scroll around, just like they were using a scroll view on iOS.  However, I know Android doesn't support the same kind of scroll view, so I opted to use an ImageView.

I'm unable to display this image properly or at least the way I'd like (without it being blurry when you zoom in) because of memory issues.  Has anyone found a way to make large scrollable images work in Titanium on Android without potential memory crashes?

I tried WebView also, but it seemed to resize my image and when you zoomed it was blurry as well.  I was hoping Android webview supported SVG, but it looks like they don't on a majority of devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by far the best answer I've found:

http://www.tenxperts.com/2011/07/13/working-with-large-images-in-android/

I tried it and it works well with Titanium web views.